# Is there any database of every position ever played in a recorded game?

Tags: database

Is there any database of every position ever played in a recorded game? I don't ask of every possible position in chess, or "solving" chess. Only the positions that were played in a recorded game. Ideally, i would like to find for a position how many times it has been recorded to have been played and who won.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any database of every position ever played in a recorded game

No database is perfect. I would say no for your question.

Sounds like you're looking for the most complete database? I propose:

- Purchase Chessbase Mega Database (many games already!)
- Data mine www.chessgames.com and https://www.365chess.com (you may need a script)
- Download all TWIC games
- Download lichess games
- Download FICS games
- Download MillionBase database

Perform an union operation on all those games.